# How do I share single list between two infinite loop threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have data structure (i.e. queue, stack or list). There is infinite loop (in thread 1) that inserts objects into that data structure, and there is another infinite loop (in thread 2) that takes objects from that data structure and does some processing on it.  I don't want the processing loop to block the insert loop.

How can I do this correctly in Java, to share a single data structure between two threads with synchronization and concurrent read/write from the two different threads? Is there any data structure in java concurrent API (java 7) that I can use? is there any recommendation to solve this issue?

Comment: have a look at java concurrency package  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [non-blocking data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824225/what-is-non-blocking-concurrency-and-how-is-it-different-than-normal-concurren), say [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).  It will accept entries to the queue and requests to it without blocking either, making it very [simple to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616484/how-to-use-concurrentlinkedqueue) without implementing anything fancy.

**Further Reading** (Into the theory behind non-blocking)

- ['Efficient and PracticalNon-Blocking Data Structures', H˚akan Sundell](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~tsigas/papers/Haakan-Thesis.pdf)
- ['Proving That Non-Blocking Algorithms Don’t Block', Alexey Gotsman et al](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mjp41/liveness.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @Ross for sharing this helpful information and editing the question as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Java's [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) seems like your best bet for a FIFO ordered queue.